# Modify and update camera frame via GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I am working with a `GLSurfaceView` activity to display the camera frame on an android device. As I am newb in `OpenGl Es`, I wondered how I can get the image buffer and modify it, then display the modified frame on the phone?

In my Renderer class which implements `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, I call a native function:

```
public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    MyJNINative.render();
  }
...
}
```

The `API` I am working with, provided a `connectCallBack` method that enables accessing image buffer via something like `onFrameAvailableNow`.
So I have already the image buffer which is unfortunately of `const` type. So my modifications to it will not get reflected.

Now my question is how to add some `gl` methods to modify the image buffer that can be reflected on the display?

My native renderer:

```
Java_com_project_MyJNINative_render(
        JNIEnv*, jobject) {
    // Let's say I have image buffer here called "uint_8t* buffer"
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // UpdateTexture() 
    api_handler.UpdateTexture());
    gl_vid_obj->Render(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::mat4(1.0f));    
    /// I NEED SOME CODE HERE TO set gl buffer
}
```

Comment: Where is the Camera output being sent? You can only have one producer attached to a Surface at a time, so you can either send the Camera output there or the GLES rendering. Are you receiving the Camera output on a SurfaceTexture? What sort of modifications are you attempting to do?

Comment: @fadden The camera output is rendered to be displayed. And yes I am receiving camera output on `gl` surface texture. I need to change some random pixels in the current frame.

Comment: The Camera image is in an "external" texture. You can do most things with it that you can any other GLES texture. Editing textures from C++ or Java isn't straightforward. Rendering the texture and then drawing on top of it is much easier. I still don't really know what it is you're trying to do, but if you want something more complex than drawing over it, perhaps filtering is what you want? Example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: @fadden Yes, filtering and image processing stuffs are what I exactly need. By Looking at the code form the `yTube` link, I concluded that it is not that straight forward. However, I wondered it could be easier as I already captured the raw frame buffer. and what I need else, is updating the `GLSurfaceView`

Comment: The Grafika demo is a fairly straightforward example of using a GLES fragment shader to apply a convolution filter. If you want to do the work on the GPU, you can either do something similar, or feed the Camera output to Renderscript and do the work that way (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). You can't access the Camera frame via an FBO because it's an "external" texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden) explained, you cannot change the preview buffer that is connected to SurfaceTexture. But you *can* obtain the preview buffers with [`onPreviewFrame()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame(byte[],%20android.hardware.Camera)), modify it and push the result to OpenGL via [`glTexSubImage2D()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml). There are two pitfalls: you should hide the actual preview (probably connecting it to a texture that will not be visible on your GL surface), and you should do all processing fast enough (20 FPS at least for the "preview" to look natural).

Comment: Yeah, apparently this is the only easy solution for now. But my processing should not block glTexImage2D, should it?

Comment: Generally speaking, you render on the OpenGL thread, this is where you should not block (and not on the UI thread, naturally). But your processing may take time - result will be "lag" between camera position and preview.