# Get and modify image buffer from native callback

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I was trying to connect my callback function via the `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable`. I was able to connect it and accessing the `TangoImageBuffer`. However, I noticed that the buffer is `const` and can not be updated. I need to modify the image data for some image processing purposes. Like contour detection and displaying it.

So my question is how can we change the `TangoJNINative_render` method to update `gl buffer`.

Here is how the renederer function looks like:

```
Java_com_project_TangoJNINative_render(
        JNIEnv*, jobject) {
    // Let's say I have image buffer here called "uint_8t* buffer"
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);

    // UpdateTexture() 
    tango_handler.UpdateColorTexture());
    /// I NEED SOME CODE HERE TO set gl buffer 
    video_overlay->Render(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::mat4(1.0f));    
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is some overlap between this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359081/modify-and-update-camera-frame-via-glsurfaceview -- is this a different question?

Comment: @fadden The link you mentioned refers to a more general question. This one is specifically for `Tango`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to regular Camera API, you can receive `TangoImageBuffer`, manipulate the pixels and assign them to your own texture (not the one provided by Tango), and display this texture instead of `TextureRenderer` and the like.